# Accessing port 7000 from openshift server

Tags: openshift, firewall

I have set up a openshift server (free) with php cartridge. During the operation, I want to call a service hosted with port 7000. Ex. www.mydomain.com:7000/service

When I try this with curl

> curl -v www.mydomain.com:7000/service

I am getting "Failed to connect (IP)....Permission denied" message. Even I can't telnet as "telnet test.mydomain.com 7000", ended with "Permission denied".

Should I have to do any setting for firewall or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to access your app via port 7000. Check out [What external ports are available on OpenShift?](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203263674-What-external-ports-are-available-on-OpenShift-)